# What different JS classes can HTML Elements be?

Tags: javascript, html, class

What I want to know is what different JavaScript classes can HTML Elements be?  For example:

1. Lots of HTML elements are of class `HTMLElement`.
2. `<svg>` is of class `SVGElement`.

Are there any other classes for elements that should be taken account of?

Comment: have a read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement see the menu item in the left hand "Related pages for HTML DOM". read that, then [edit 9 your question to make it easier to answer it

Comment: Check the [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API)

Comment: Taken account of for what purpose? Worrying about what JS classes HTML elements can be is a pretty esoteric concern....

Comment: To be very clear, JavaScript does not actually have an internal "Class" construct. `class` is just a keyword in JavaScript that allows for more traditional OOP type syntax. Internally, JavaScript has native types and Object instances. HTML Elements are Objects and those objects are organized based on what interface they implement. Therefore, the best answer to your question is to understand the different [HTML DOM Element Interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API#HTML_element_interfaces), which @Robert answers below.

Comment: @JaredSmith : I am building a JS library and I want to be able to make an HTML element given by the user into an object (that contains methods to perform).  It should be able to take a single element, or an array of elements.  All I want to test is if it is an element, then pass `[x]`, else pass `x` because my object requires an array (of HTML elements).  So I want to test for if `x` is an element like that (and I want to allow all types of elements too).

Comment: Then all you have to do is check the argument to see if its [`.nodeType === 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am building a JS library and I want to be able to make an HTML
> element given by the user into an object (that contains methods to
> perform). It should be able to take a single element, or an array of
> elements. All I want to test is if it is an element, then pass [x],
> else pass x because my object requires an array (of HTML elements). So
> I want to test for if x is an element like that (and I want to allow
> all types of elements too).

Then all you have to do is check the argument to see if its [`.nodeType === 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).

```js
let el = document.querySelector("div");
let att = el.getAttribute("title");
console.log(el.nodeType, el.nodeName);
console.log(el.firstChild.nodeType, el.textContent);
```

```html
<div title="I'm the value of an attribute node">I'm a text node within an element node.</div>
```

Comment: this looks like an interesting solution.  I'll try this too.